# How to list X numbers in base of Y?

Tags: python, math

I have to create a list in Python of all the numbers of length X where each digit is lower than 3. for example, for length 4:
`[[0000],[0001],[0002],[0010],[0011],...]` and so on..
I have some ideas. but I can't think of any good, performant solution.

I thought about doing the following:

1. Create a function "Is each number's digits < 2"
2. Loop over 9999 numbers and run the functions on them. Then add to the list.

To summerize, I want to **list all numbers that < x in base of 3**

edit:
this can help: `[(x,y,z) for x in xrange(3) for y in xrange(3) for z in xrange(3)]`.
It is even better for me that the outpot is in generator. but this answer isn't dynamic. i can't change its length.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I've just tought about using "base of 3"

Comment: And why is it downvoted?

Comment: I didnt downvote it. I just left that comment.

Comment: Can you show an attempt of what you have tried? Maybe something that tries to generate all permutations of 0's and 1's in a list with 4 elements, or something that tries to create all possible lists first and then attempts to filter them.

Comment: This can help: `[(x,y,z) for x in xrange(3) for y in xrange(3) for z in xrange(3)]`

Comment: Every digit being smaller than three implies that the number is smaller than 3^n (where n is the "length"), so just represent the numbers from 0 to 3^n in base-3.

Comment: ok now what restriction do you want to put on the sum of x+y+z?

Comment: @Blender thats exactly what im trying to do.

Comment: @Nirock: So where are you stuck? Base-conversion isn't an obscure process. There's a ton of material and sample code out there.

Comment: @Blender I didn't think of it as a base of 3 before. The idea came up after writing the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `itertools.product`:

```
[''.join(map(str,tup)) for tup in product(range(3),repeat=4)]
```

I joined them into strings since [0000] will just display as [0].  You could just leave them as tuples and get rid of all the `join(map(str...` mumbo jumbo.  In that case you don't even need the list comp, it's just

```
list(product(range(4),repeat=3))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following in not exactly what you asked for, but it comes close:

```
from itertools import product

def create_list(x):
    return list(product(range(3), repeat=x))

print create_list(3)
```

This will print:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2),
 (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2),
 (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2),
 (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2),
 (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```

Comment: Not exactly what i aked for. but thats exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @dparpyani You might want to generalize it a bit, by changing `lst = [0, 1, 2]` to `lst = range(3)`

Comment: Thanks alot to all of you. How did you know about product() function?

Comment: @Nirock [Python documentation: itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). There is some other great stuff there as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Come up with a rule that orders all the responses so that each one comes either before or after each other one.
2. Write code to find the first response.
3. Write code to determine if a response is the last response.
4. Write code to convert a response into the next response.

Now the algorithm is trivial:

1. Set an indicator to the first response from `2` above.
2. Output the current value of the indicator.
3. If the indicator is the last response from `3` above, stop.
4. Increment the indicator using `4` above.
5. Go to step 2.

I would suggest you order them numerically, so four four digits, it would be 0000, 0001, 0002, 0010, 0011, and so on. The first response is then all zeroes. The last response is all twos. This just leaves the issue of writing the code to increment to the next response.

Answer (score 1):

```
inputBase, expectedSize = 2, 3

def convertToBase(num, base):
    result, current = [], 0
    if not num: result.append(0)
    while num:
        result.append((num % base))
        current += 1
        num /= base
    result.reverse()
    return result, current

currentNum, result = 0, []
while True:
    based, size = convertToBase(currentNum, inputBase)
    if size > expectedSize: break
    while len(based) < expectedSize:
        based.insert(0, 0)
    result.append(based)
    currentNum += 1

print result
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Just change

```
inputBase, expectedSize = 2, 3
```

to any base and the number of digits you want.

Comment: Thats very nice. But I need it to be a little manipulated. I need it to be represented like this: `[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[1,0,0],[1,0,1]]` .
Altough its defenetly answers my question.

Comment: @Nirock Just updated my solution. Please check now. But dparpyani's solution is the best.

Comment: @Nirock Check roippi's solution as well. Its awesome. Its the best you can get.

Comment: How do i tick 2 answers? :P